# How to fill of water the river between two lines?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, topology

I want to fill the river with water, I try from line to polygons but doesn't work and it was the result:

[image]

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: What's the second map? Are the black lines the edges of the river system? Is it quite complex, with islands and branches etc?

Comment: Depending on where you got the data, the simplest way could be to download a polygon file rather than a line file. [NHD](http://nhd.usgs.gov/data.html)

Comment: One option you have is closing the river edges with lines (enabling the snapping option ir order to adjust it correctly) and then try again the "Line to polygon" system you already tried.

Comment: @Spacedman the second map the black lines is the river edge as you said,  and it is complex because the that island, I know.

Comment: @AndreuAmoros , I am going to try that, I will let you know the result, thanks...